# Iterating the entire list

Tags: python, api, flask

My code hits the variable end point and then creates the logfile(UUID.log) these log files are unique for every hit. Inside every log file there is a json(process_name,Process_id) where endpoint name gets logged in as a process_name.

The if condition checks in for the duplicate process_name inside the log files before creating a new file to ensure that the log file with duplicate process_name do not get logged in.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import json
import uuid
import os
import test1


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/<string:name>')
def get_stats(name):
    proceuudi = uuid.uuid4()
    stat = [
        {
            'process_id': str(proceuudi),
            'process_name': name 
        }
    ]
    os.chdir("file_path")
    files = os.listdir('file_path')
    l=[]
    for i in files:
        with open(i) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            for j in data:
                l.append(j)
    for j in l: 
        print(j)           
        if j['process_name'] != name:
            with open(str(proceuudi) + '.log', 'w+') as f:  # writing JSON object
               json.dump(stat, f)  
            return jsonify({'stats':stat})
        else:    
            return 'Process already running'
app.run(port = 6011)
```

Whenever i am trying to parse the list(l=[]) containing the process_name and process_id. I am not able to parse the entire list. it is only checking at  the starting index. if it gets j['process_name'] != name at the first index it is getting returned. Is there a way through which entire list could be parsed and then if the process_name do not exist in any log file the log file with that process name gets created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use set to hold `process_name` as this will avoid scanning whole list.
2. don't scan all files on every call use global variable to hold name in memory

```
app = Flask(__name__)    
# use set  as membership (in operator) check is O(1)
l = set()
running = False

@app.route('/<string:name>')
def get_stats(name):
    global l, running
    proceuudi = uuid.uuid4()
    # why list as from the code it is clear that one file will have only one entry
    stat = [
        {
            'process_id': str(proceuudi),
            'process_name': name 
        }
    ]

    # take all name at the start of server
    if not running:
        # better to write new function for this stuff
        files = os.listdir('./file_path')
        print files
        for i in files:
            with open("./file_path/"+i) as f:
                data = json.load(f)
                for j in data:
                    l.add(j["process_name"])
        running = True

    if name in l:
        # use jsonfy here too 
        return jsonify("proces running")
    else:
        # add new process_name to in momery variable
        l.add(stat[0]["process_name"])
        with open("./file_path/"+str(proceuudi) + '.log', 'w+') as f:  # writing JSON object
           json.dump(stat, f)  
        return jsonify({'stats':stat})

app.run(port = 6011)
```

NOTE: [use code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for such type of question.